# segmentation fault on buffer overflow

Tags: c, return, buffer, warnings

I am having trouble to run this c code. When I do i get segmentation fault and an error with 'return' return 0xdeadbeef;

Anyone have any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int lame(unsigned int size, unsigned int value){

unsigned int array1[4];
unsigned int array2[6];
array2[5] = value;
memcpy(&array1, &array2, size * sizeof(unsigned int));

return 1;
}

void awesome(){
printf("awwwwwww yeaaahhhhh! All awesome, all the time!\n");
}

main(unsigned int argc, char ** argv){
unsigned int size, value;
size = strtoul(argv[1], 0, 10);
value = strtoul(argv[2], 0, 16);

if(!lame(size, value)){
    awesome();
}
else{
    printf("I am soooo lame :(\n");
}

return 0xdeadbeef;
}
```

Comment: don't post a link to code.  Especially don't post a link to IMAGE of code.  Post the representative code here in your post

Comment: First of all, don't post links to code, links can go stale and make your question worthless. Second of all, and more important, don't post images of text! That makes it completely impossible for us to copy and paste it to try it out ourselves. Instead you should copy and paste the text and put into the question body, as text.

Comment: There is at least one bug on almost every line of your code. You need an introductory programming course, not a Q&A site.

Comment: Also, if you get crashes, then you should run in a debugger to locate the crashes in your code. Furthermore, if you have buffer overflow, then you have undefined behavior which is bad and could cause any kind of stuff to happen.

Comment: I have now copied the code. Sorry for that

Comment: At first, look at description - unsigned long int strtoul (const char* str, char** endptr, int base);  At second, check boundaries in memcpy - you have 2 arrays of 4 and 6 elements, but size is 10. And main question - What do you want to check/do by this code?

Comment: For this code i wanted to run a challenge for buffer overflow  to find the memory address to show the line "awwwwwww yeaaahhhhh! All awesome, all the time!"

Comment: `main` has return type `void` yet you return a value. Start by reading compiler warnings.

Comment: thanks i noticed that after but when i compile i still get segmentation faults :(

Answer (score 2):

I said that there was "at least one bug on almost every line of your code" and now I will list them.  If I don't have any comments on a line, there are no *bugs* on that line, but you also need to read up on proper code formatting and style.

```
int lame(unsigned int size, unsigned int value){
unsigned int array1[4];
unsigned int array2[6];
array2[5] = value;
memcpy(&array1, &array2, size * sizeof(unsigned int));
return 1;
}
```

Undefined behavior on the `memcpy` line if `size` is larger than 4.  Since `size` is taken from user input, this program contains a buffer overflow vulnerability, albeit one that might be hard to exploit.  (You need to read "[Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html).")

This function has no externally visible side effects.  The compiler may, and probably will, delete *all of its code* except the `return 1`.

Functions that always return the same constant value should be refactored to return `void`.  Functions that are not used outside the current file should be declared `static`.

```
void awesome(){
printf("awwwwwww yeaaahhhhh! All awesome, all the time!\n");
}
```

This use of `printf` can be replaced by `puts`.  Functions that are not used outside the current file should be declared `static`.

```
main(unsigned int argc, char ** argv){
```

The first argument to `main` must have type `int`, not `unsigned int`.  The return type (which must be `int`, not `void`) is missing; many compilers will tolerate this (treating it as implicitly returning `int`) for backward compatibility with pre-C89 code, but it's still Wrong.

```
unsigned int size, value;
size = strtoul(argv[1], 0, 10);
value = strtoul(argv[2], 0, 16);
```

Both `size` and `value` should be `unsigned long` for consistency with what `strtoul` returns.

Undefined behavior if there are fewer than two command-line arguments.

Need to check both calls to `strtoul` for failure.  This is nontrivial; read the [EXAMPLES section of the OpenBSD manpage for `strtoul`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man3/strtoul.3#x4558414d504c4553) to learn how to do it *correctly*.

However, props for using `strtoul` rather than `atoi` (which you *can't* check for failure) or `sscanf` (which has undefined behavior on integer overflow).

```
if(!lame(size, value)){
    awesome();
}
else{
    printf("I am soooo lame :(\n");
}
```

The compiler can and will determine that `lame` always returns 1, and optimize out the call to `awesome`.  (In fact, it would be entitled to optimize out *everything* but the above `printf`, as all control flow paths either trigger undefined behavior or they reach this `printf`, and there are no other externally visible effects.  The compilers I have readily to hand are not quite that clever, but they *do* remove the if-then-else and all the code inside `lame`.)

This use of `printf` can also be replaced by `puts`.

You will automatically become 23% less lame the moment you stop calling yourself lame.

```
return 0xdeadbeef;
```

The value returned by `main` is meaningful.  0 means success of the overall program, any other value means some sort of failure.  Always return 0 unless you intend to indicate failure.  Also, only values in the range [0, 127] can be reliably received by the parent process cross-platform; `0xdeadbeef` is Right Out.

In your screenshot, `main` returned `void` instead of having a missing return type; that plus a `return` statement with a value should have caused the program to fail to *compile*.  Your compiler might tolerate it in `main`, though.

Comment: thanks so much but i am still very puzzled! could you give me an example of the return 1 section of this working please?

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you want an example of.

Comment: as in how to fix the memcpy line (lame function)

Comment: I cannot tell you what the `memcpy` line *should* do, because the program-as-a-whole doesn't do anything meaningful, or even anything that makes sense.  However, you must *always* make certain, each time you call `memcpy`, that its third argument cannot be larger than the allocated size of its first argument.  In this case that would translate to: `size` must be no more than 4.

Comment: All i wanted to do was to make a simple buffer overflow challenge whereby the user would have to try and overun the buffers boundary. I thought i was on the right track with this?. this challenge when executed is supposed to print out I am soooo lame :( message. The challenge is to make the program print out awwwwwww yeaaahhhhh! All awesome, all the time! instead.

Comment: OK, you're deliberately trying to write a program with a buffer overflow vuln in it.  My advice then is: read "Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit."  Make a list of *everything* Aleph One says that you don't understand *perfectly*.  Research all those things; recurse on anything you don't understand that comes up while researching.  Repeat until you understand the entire article perfectly.  Now you should be able to proceed.